# Xcode Interface Builder - Show objects out of frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, scrollview, xib

I am building a vertical iPhone XIB file in the interface builder that contains a vertical scrolling ScrollView.  The scrollview has about 19 buttons for a total height of about 3 times the iPhone screen's height.

This means I can't see the buttons at the bottom of the scrollview without giving the scrollview a negative Y-position setting. It gets really annoying every time I have to adjust the scrollview's Y-position just to see my buttons at the bottom of the scrollview because the XIB's frame "hides" everything that extends beyond its frame.

This has annoyed me for several years.  Is there a setting somewhere that lets me see the XIB's frame (crop) boundaries, but also lets me see everything that extends *beyond* the frame's boundaries??  I never understood why it hides everything outside of the frame.  It is restricting and slows down the work process when working with very tall ScrollViews.

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: you can have a view that is full height in the xib then programmatically set it as the `contentView` of your scroll view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, just do this in order to increase the visible canvas of your ViewController, that has scrollView (these metrics are simulated, so don't worry, it will not affect your view in simulator/device in any way):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Soberman, thanks!!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I am using Xcode 6.1 so I had to look in the Attributes Inspector instead of the Size Inspector to change Simulated Metrics for the View, but yes, now I can finally see the entire ScrollView!! Thank you very much for the images as well.

Comment: No problems, glad could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible to scroll the content view of a scroll view in IB by pressing the option, or another modifier key while the scroll view was selected and you did a scroll.

Unfortunately, I noticed that this feature broke in one of the later Xcode 6 updates, or Xcode 7 betas, and (because I’m not doing a lot of UI stuff lately) it does not seem to have been fixed again.

[Please file a bug on this](https://bugreport.apple.com/), because it sure won’t be fixed if the feature isn’t missed…